# How to run a php project in localhost using XAMPP?

Tags: php

First of all, I'm using Kali Linux. I have a project, it's a folder with .php files. I want to run it to see it on the browser, so it needs to be localhost. Folder name is "CMSsite". I moved the folder to /opt/lampp/htdocs folder to access it through typing on the browser localhost/CMSsite. When I open the browser and type localhost/CMSsite/ I see the message "The requested URL was not found on the server"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDxc.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Probabely something in the root of ```htdocs``` is redirecting all requests to a controller file. Try clearing root or changing the controller file.

Comment: Should I change something in the apache configuration file?